# Landscape orientation fails with screen flashes

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape

I have a simple application that is working properly when opens in portrait mode however, when it programmatically switched the layout orientation to landscape it throws a lot of logcat errors and screen is starting to flashes.. I don't know what's going on?

My LogCat

> 08-29 18:35:05.596 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
>   08-29 18:35:05.694 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/WindowDecorActionBar: should not do the transition or the transition anim is null or it is running or the mContainer view is null or mContainer view hasn't been drawn to screen 
>   08-29 18:35:05.695 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/CfgFilePolicy: No config file found for:/themes/diff/icons
>       CFG_DIRS length : 11
>   08-29 18:35:05.704 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
>   08-29 18:35:05.817 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/WindowDecorActionBar: should not do the transition or the transition anim is null or it is running or the mContainer view is null or mContainer view hasn't been drawn to screen 
>   08-29 18:35:05.818 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/CfgFilePolicy: No config file found for:/themes/diff/icons
>       CFG_DIRS length : 11
>   08-29 18:35:05.828 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
>   08-29 18:35:05.930 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/WindowDecorActionBar: should not do the transition or the transition anim is null or it is running or the mContainer view is null or mContainer view hasn't been drawn to screen 
>   08-29 18:35:05.931 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/CfgFilePolicy: No config file found for:/themes/diff/icons
>       CFG_DIRS length : 11
>   08-29 18:35:05.939 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
>   08-29 18:35:06.053 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/WindowDecorActionBar: should not do the transition or the transition anim is null or it is running or the mContainer view is null or mContainer view hasn't been drawn to screen 
>   08-29 18:35:06.053 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube W/CfgFilePolicy: No config file found for:/themes/diff/icons
>       CFG_DIRS length : 11
>   08-29 18:35:06.062 17840-17840/com.mediamaster.kidstube I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config

Comment: "programmatically switched the layout orientation to landscape": how are you doing this?

Comment: either by entering the below or switch the phone orientation with no code : setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: Also I can see from logcat that the activity is starting to go to states: paused.resumed and created

Comment: I get arround the problem by adding the below condition in the manifext.xml 

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add the following to the activity in manifest.xml

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"